# How to prevent Spring from logging WARNs "o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound"?

Tags: java, spring, exception, logging

I'm new here and my English level isn't that good, so take good care of me, please! :D

So... whenever I create a request to an unmapped URI, I log in using an `ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)` to customize the return to the client.

That configuration was only possible because I've changes the `application.properties` file and added the following lines:

```js
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

The problem is that I am logging it two times now; one from Spring and the other from my `ExceptionHandler`...

Here is the created handler:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException exception) {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(
        HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
        "There was a unexpected request.",
        "There is no support for the requested URI. Inexistant endpoint."
    );
        
    return new ResponseEntity<ApiError>(apiError, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

The object returned is a `ResponseEntity` of an `ApiError`, here is the class:

```java
@Getter
private class ApiError {
    
    private String statusDescription;
    private String clientMessage;
    private String developerMessage;
    
    public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String clientMessage, String developerMessage) {
        this.statusDescription = generateStatusMessage(status);
        this.clientMessage = clientMessage;
        this.developerMessage = developerMessage;
        logException(developerMessage);
    }
    
    private String generateStatusMessage(HttpStatus status) {
        return status.value() + " - " + status.name();
    }
    
    private void logException(String message) {
        log.warn(message);
    }
    
}
```

And, finally, here is the log:

```sh
2020-07-17 13:21:34.602  WARN 17801 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /api/uri/test
2020-07-17 13:21:34.604  WARN 17801 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] f.i.g.r.rest.RestExceptionHandler        : There is no support for the requested URI. Inexistant endpoint.
```

So, any ideas on how can I maintain my custom log & exception without showing the
`PageNotFound` warn from Spring?

Comment: configure your logger to suppress the spring warning (for example by setting the severity for logger org.spring.web.servlet.PageNotFound to ERROR).

Comment: And how exactly should I set that severity?

Comment: Setting the severity threshold at which the logger prints depends on the logger implementation (logback, log4j, ...) you are using. Typically there is a log config file that you would have to adapt.